# Кривой поворот текстуры

Tags: c++, opengl

Пишу программу, которая рисует сферу, накладывает на нее текстуру земли и та в итоге вращается вокруг своей оси.

Вот так планета выглядит в первые секунды  вращения:

[image: picture_1]

Однако, в какой-то момент происходит следующее:

[image: puctire_2]

Так же проблемы возникают при вращении относительно других осей.

Код программы привожу ниже:

```
#include <GL/freeglut.h> 
#include "soil.h"

#include <iostream>

GLuint texture[1];
GLUquadricObj *sphere;
static GLint angle = 0;

void drawEarth()
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    gluQuadricTexture(sphere, GLU_TRUE);
    gluQuadricNormals(sphere, GLU_FLAT);
    gluSphere(sphere, 1, 50, 50);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(angle, 1, 1, 0);
    drawEarth();
    glPopMatrix();
    
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void timer(int = 0)
{
    display();
    angle += 1;
    angle %= 360;
    glutTimerFunc(10, timer, 0);
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    if (h == 0) h = 1;

    float k = (float)w / h;
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    if (w > h)
        glOrtho(-2 * k, 2 * k, -2, 2, -5, 10);
    else
        glOrtho(-2, 2, -2 / k, 2 / k, -5, 10);
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

bool loadTextures()
{
    texture[0] = SOIL_load_OGL_texture
    (
        "C:\\Users\\anton\\source\\repos\\demoGl\\demoGl\\earth.bmp",
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y
    );

    if (texture[0] == 0)
        return false;

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    return true;
}

//void initLight()
//{
//  GLfloat light0_diffuse[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };           
//  GLfloat light0_direction[] = { 0.2f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f };  
//
//  glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
//  glLightModelf(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_LOCAL_VIEWER, GL_TRUE);
//  glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
//
//  glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
//  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light0_diffuse);
//  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light0_direction);
//}

void myInit()
{
    if (!loadTextures())
    {
        std::cerr << "failed to load textures . . ." << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-2, 2, -2, 2, -5, 10);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    sphere = gluNewQuadric();

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    timer();
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("demo");

    myInit();

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Скажите, проблема в способе загрузки и указания текстуры, или быть может в ней самой?

Ссылка на пикчу: https://ibb.co/7Sm6D5q

Comment: Добавил буфер глубины, проблема исчезла)0